# Ruby Error uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am just starting with Ruby on rails and following a tutorial from https://mackenziechild.me/12-in-12/3/

at some point i have an error

```
    Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/cities/_form.html.haml where line #26 raised: uninitialized constant City::Direction
```

and points to:

```
    .col-md-6
               %h3 How to get There ?
               #getthere
                   = f.simple_fields_for :directions do |direction|
                       = render 'direction_fields', :f => direction
                   .links
                       = link_to_add_association 'Add Directions', f, :directions, class: "btn btn-default add-button"
```

I have no idea where to look, my database was created fine so far as i know. Anyone can help me here ?

i have this database

```
    class CreateDirections < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :directions do |t|
          t.text :getthere
          t.belongs_to :city, index: true

          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```

and this

```
    class CreateCities < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :cities do |t|
          t.string :title
          t.text :description
          t.integer :user_id

          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```

and this city model

```
 class City < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :infos
    has_many :directions

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :infos, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['information'].blank? },
    allow_destroy: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :directions, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['getthere'].blank? },
    allow_destroy: true

    validates :title, :description, :image, presence: true
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "163x163#"}
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

 end
```

Comment: oh sorry. let me see it again

Comment: did you `rake db:migrate` ?? and what is on line 26 ??

Comment: Do you have `Direction` model? It should be placed in `app/models/direction.rb` file.

Comment: yes this is in it

    class Directions < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :city
    end

Comment: sorry i don't know how to format a block of code here in the comments

Comment: Just a guess, but Rails usually expects model names to be singular, hence why it's looking for a model named `Direction`, whereas yours is named `Directions`

Comment: @Slicedpan Super !! that solved it. thanks a lot !!! i have to  pay more attention next time :)

Comment: @BjornMorrhaye you can use backticks [the grave accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) to put `code` in comments